# Creating search box using input() method in python

Tags: python

I am unable to write code for creating a search box in python which will search for elements in a list irrespective of the CASE of the input and give me the output.

```
Fruit=['Apple', 'Guava', 'Mango', 'watermelon']
Choclate=['Candy', 'Nestle', 'dairy milk']
street_food=['Pizza', 'pani puri', 'juice']
```

##Below is the code I have written to search for items in the above lists.

```
a=input('Enter the food item')

def eating(a):

    if a in Fruit:
        print('Healthy')
    elif a in Choclate:
        print('Unhealty')
    else:
        print('Don't eat daily')


##calling the function        
eating(a)
```

Problem/Questions-

1)The problem with the above code is that I cannot search thoroughly. I have to input exactly the correct case to get the desired output. For example, if I type 'mango' instead of 'Mango', I don't get the desired result. Thus I want the code to give me correct result irrespective of the  CASE. Please help me with the correct code.

2. How to make the above code configurable? I mean how can I automatically update the lists of various food items whenever I get a request to add a new one? Right now, I have to enter it in the list manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eating(a.capitalize())` to make the first letter of the input capitalized. alternatively you can use `eating(a.lower())` to make the whole input lowercase which would make "mAnGo" a valid input (this would require you to change all the elements in the arrays to only be lowercase aswell)

Answer (score 0):

1. For this problem, first, you need the data at same case, i.e. all lowercase or all uppercase, e.g. `['mango', 'apple']`. Then you can use `.lower()` and `.upper()` in the if block, or just lower it after receiving input by `input().lower()`

```
Fruit=['apple', 'guava', 'mango', 'watermelon']
Choclate=['candy', 'nestle', 'dairy milk']
street_food=['pizza', 'pani puri', 'juice']

a=input('Enter the food item')

def eating(a):
    if a.lower() in Fruit:
        print('Healthy')
    elif a.lower() in Choclate:
        print('Unhealty')
    else:
        print('Don't eat daily')


##calling the function        
eating(a)
```

2. This depends. If you wish your program to be able to do either add to list or just do `eating()`. You need to add one more function and another input to distinguish the treatment. Example

```
def insert(a, dest):
    if dest == 'fruit':
        Fruit.append(a)

a=input('Enter the food item')
whatToDo = input('What to do with this food?')
if whatToDo == '1':
    eating(a)
elif whatToDo == '2':
    dest = input('select the list:')
    insert(a, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside of looping through all list entries and checking them one by one you can join your lists to easily put them to lower. Then it is working:

```
Fruit=['Apple', 'Guava', 'Mango', 'watermelon']
Choclate=['Candy', 'Nestle', 'dairy milk']
street_food=['Pizza', 'pani puri', 'juice']

a=input('Enter the food item: ')
a=a.lower()


def eating(a):

    if a in ", ".join(Fruit).lower():
        print('Healthy')
    elif a in ", ".join(Choclate).lower():
        print('Unhealty')
    else:
        print("Don't eat daily")   # you get a bug here with single quotes


##calling the function        
eating(a)
```

In order to edit your lists, `exec` comes in handy to keep everything simple.
The `print(..., file=...)` command prints Fruit and Choclate to an init script. The program tries to silently execute that script on startup:

```
Fruit=['Apple', 'Guava', 'Mango', 'watermelon']
Choclate=['Candy', 'Nestle', 'dairy milk']
street_food=['Pizza', 'pani puri', 'juice']

## execute init script if it exists
try: exec(open("fat-init.py").read())
except FileNotFoundError: pass


def eating(a):

    if a in ", ".join(Fruit).lower():
        print('Healthy')
    elif a in ", ".join(Choclate).lower():
        print('Unhealty')
    else:
        b=input("Don't eat daily, or append to Fruit/Chocolate: ").capitalize()
        if b in ["Fruit", "Choclate"]:
            exec(b + "+=['" + a + "'];print('" + b + " ='," + b + ")")
            print("Fruit=" + str(Fruit) + ";Choclate=" + str(Choclate),
                file=open("fat-init.py", "w"))

## calling the function
while 1:
  a=input('Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): ')
  eating(a.lower().replace('"', '').replace("'", ''))
```

Since there is no exit condition you have to hit ctrl+c to exit. Output:

```
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): banana
Don't eat daily, or append to Fruit/Chocolate: fruit
Fruit = ['Apple', 'Guava', 'Mango', 'watermelon', 'banana']
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): banana
Healthy
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/how/to/get/fat.py", line 1337, in <module>
    a=input('Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): ')
KeyboardInterrupt
```

To flex this even further and allow for new types of food you better put everything within dictionaries instead of evaluating every list. The above code is a bit unusual that it evaluates into the lists you defined. The pythonic way is more like this:

```
Food={'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Guava', 'Mango', 'watermelon'],
     'Choclate': ['Candy', 'Nestle', 'dairy milk'],
     'street_food': ['Pizza', 'pani puri', 'juice']
}
State={ 'Fruit': 'Healthy', 'Choclate': 'Unhealty', 'street_food': 'Tasty' }


## execute init script if it exists
try: exec(open("test-init.py").read())
except FileNotFoundError: pass

def eating(a):
    for k, v in Food.items():
        if a.lower() in ", ".join(v + [k]).lower():
            print(f"{a} is {State[k]}")
            break
    else:
        k=input(f"Don't eat daily, or append to {list(Food)}: ")
        k=''.join ( filter ( str.isalpha, k.capitalize() ) )
        if not k in Food:
            v=input("What is this new type of food (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): ")
            Food[k]=[]
            State[k]=v.replace('"', '').replace("'", "")
        Food[k]+=[a]
        print(f"{k} = {Food[k]}")
        print(f"Food={str(Food)};State={str(State)}",
              file=open("test-init.py", "w"))

## calling the function
while 1:
  a=input('Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): ')
  eating(a.replace('"', '').replace("'", ""))
```

If you use an init script to store your food types during program breaks, you have to simply ensure: dictionary keys have to contain only letters and dictionary values should not contain quotes. Output:

```
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): fruit
fruit is Healthy
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): choclate
choclate is Unhealty
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): banana
Don't eat daily, or append to ['Fruit', 'Choclate', 'street_food']: fruit
Fruit = ['Apple', 'Guava', 'Mango', 'watermelon', 'banana']
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): banana
banana is Healthy
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): cheese
Don't eat daily, or append to ['Fruit', 'Choclate', 'street_food']: smile
What is this new type of food (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): good
Smile = ['cheese']
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): smile
smile is good
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): cheese
cheese is good
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Downloads/test.py", line 155, in <module>
    a=input('Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): ')
KeyboardInterrupt

~/Downloads$ python3 test.py
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit): smile
smile is good
Enter the food item (ctrl+c/z/d to exit):
```